# How to configure Sendmail?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, sendmail, aix

How can I learn to configure sendmail on Unix-aix? Note that I don't have a DNS server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend grabbing O'Reilly's Sendmail book (Bat on front).

Answer (score 2):

[UNIX and Linux System Administration Handbook](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/bookseller/product/UNIX-and-Linux-System-Administration-Handbook/9780131480056.page) Chapter 20 is the best!